# Explaining classes

Tags: c++, syntax

I have a couple of syntax questions that I'm sure most people could answer but this is all foreign to me and I worked through a class tutorial but it left a few questions unanswered.

This code is the declaration line of a class function and inside the parenthesis are the values to be passed. correct?

```
void HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC::SetRegisterLocations(int bus, int ha, int chan, int counterNumber)  
{
_ha = ha;
_chan = chan;
_counterNumber = counterNumber;
_bus = bus;
}
```

In this example what does the additional semicolon at the end enable? Where would I be looking to see what the counterNumbers are associated with?

```
HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC::HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC(int hwType, const char* pName) : HwCounterBase(pName)
{
_counterNumber = 0;
_currentConfig = 0;
_hwType = hwType;
}
```

I'm unable to post the entire source code sorry and I know that makes it more difficult but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: . . what does the additional semicolon at the end enable? I think you mean the colon. It starts an initializer list.

Comment: I may be too drunk or just blind, but which "additional semicolon" are you referring to?

Comment: yes i meant additional colon. refering to this part: : HwCounterBase(pName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
void HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC::SetRegisterLocations(int bus, int ha, int chan, int counterNumber)  
{
  ...
}
```

is the *definition* of a function. (The *declaration* is something else, and to learn the distinction you should start with a simpler example.) Its name is `SetRegisterLocations`, it is a member of the class `HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC`, it takes four arguments (all `int`), and it returns nothing (`void`).

This:

```
HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC::HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC(int hwType, const char* pName)
{
  ...
}
```

is similar, but it is a *constructor*. The name of the function is the same as the name of the function, and it has no return type (not even `void`).

This:
    HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC::HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC(int hwType, const char* pName) : HwCounterBase(pName)
    {
      ...
    }

is the same, but it has an *initializer* list (consisting of only one initializer) which sets the value (or calls the constructor) of a member variable (`HwCounterBase`).

> Where would I be looking to see what the counterNumbers are associated
>   with?

The rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

> This code is the declaration line of a class function and inside the
>   parenthesis are the values to be passed. correct?

Yes, it is, being understood that the function has to be first declared inside the class.

> In this example what does the additional <strike>semi</strike>colon at the end enable?

`HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC::HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC(..)` is a constructor for the class `HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC`.

The `:` is followed by a list of mem-initializer, a special form of initialization of data members and of the base class if necessary.  For example `HwCounterBase(pName)` means that the data member (or the base class) `HwCounterBase` is intialized by calling its constructor with the value `pName`.

Comment: More probably, `HwCounterBase` is the/a base class of `HwCounter_IVBNHSX_IMC`; `HwCounterBase(pName)` then calls the constructor of the base class and passes `pName` to it.